# rails select distinct nested associations and fetch those associations

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

i have the models `User`, `Company`, `Product`, `View`

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :views_by_user, -> { where viewable_type: User },
  as: :viewable, class_name: "View"
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :viewed, as: :viewer, class_name: "View"
  belongs_to :company
end

class View < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :viewable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :viewer, polymorphic: true
end
```

What i did with the above is, when a user views product, i save the data in the `views`

Now i want the list of distinct `companies` that have looked at my product(via `user`) and total count for my serializer. what i have done is,

```
distinct_users = @product.views_by_user
    .includes(viewer: [:company])
    .joins("left outer join users on views.viewer_id = users.id")
    .select("distinct users.company_id, views.*")
```

but with this, i would have to do something like

```
distinct_users.will_paginate(...).map(&:viewer).map(&:company)
```

is there a better way to do it? also if i use `distinct_users.count` it throws me an error

```
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function count(integer, views) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(distinct users.company_id,...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start from `Company` if this is the type of record you actually want. You can use `merge` to combine the conditions on a relation with those from another. Try this:

`Company.joins(:users => :viewed).merge(View.where(viewable: @product))`

HTH

Comment: great! this works. I am not able to find the joins syntax that you mentioned anywhere. could you please point me as to where i can read more about it? thanks.

Comment: There is an official guide available [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-nested-associations-single-level).

Comment: Note that `a: :b` and `:a => :b` are equivalent. Personally I prefer the former Syntax in most cases, but for `joins` I like the latter better.
In your question you used yet another construct: `a: [:b]`. You wrapped `:b` in an array. This is perfectly fine but unnecessary. The `joins` method can handle arrays because in some cases you might want to do something like `joins(a: [:b, :c])`.